# How do I setup and use a USB serial console adapter?

Tags: pantheon-terminal

How do I setup and use a serial console on Elementary OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like using the [Parallax USB to serial adapter](https://www.parallax.com/product/28030) because it enjoys good support on *NIX operating systems. You can pick them up in the robotics section at Frys electronics in the U.S. for around $17.

After connecting the adapter, run dmesg, you're looking for a few lines at the end like so:

```
[ 2970.548809] usb 2-1: Detected FT232RL
[ 2970.551218] usb 2-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

Note the device name 'ttyUSB0'. Run a long list on this to determine which group it is owned by;

```
$ ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Apr  8 09:24 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Add your user account to that group. This way you can run the terminal program as a non-root user.

```
sudo gpasswd -u <username> dialout
```

Log out and back in for the group change to take effect

Install the picocom terminal utility

```
sudo apt-get install -y picocom
```

Connect to the serial console using the appropriate baud rate for your target device and the device name as shown in dmesg earlier

```
picocom -b 38400 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

To exit picocom press `CTRL-a-x`